# Simple Editor for BSON Databases

Tags: json, bson

Does anyone known of  a simple utility for editing a simple BSON database/file?

Comment: i'd also be interested in this....

Comment: This would be very convenient for peeking into backups

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did You try this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bsondump/ ?

Answer (score 11):

The installation package that includes `mongodump` ('mongo-tools' on Ubuntu) should also include `bsondump`, for which the manpage says:

> bsondump - examine BSON files in a human-readable form

You can convert BSON to JSON with the following:

```
bsondump --pretty <your_file.bson
```

---

*As a data interchange format, BSON may not be suitable for editing directly.*  For manipulating a BSON dataset, you could, of course, upload it to MonogDB and work with that.  Or, you could open the `bsondump` decoded JSON in an editor.  But the [BSON Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) indicates that compatible libraries exist in several languages, which suggests that you should also be able to decode it programmatically to an internal map representation and edit that internal representation in code.

Comment: For further options/alternatives, see also [What is difference between mongodump and mongoexport?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/194370/186897) + [mongodump vs mongoexport: which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719882/mongodump-vs-mongoexport-which-is-better) and the possibility of using [`mongoimport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/) to import JSON-formatted data (after `bsondump`), but beware the [caveat about type fidelity](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/program/mongoexport/#type-fidelity).

Comment: BSON is produced with `mongodump`, as described at [How to export all collections in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11255630/86967), with 'snapshot' error addressed with `--forceTableScan` as described at [Mongodump: Unrecognized field 'snapshot'](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/215534/186897).

Comment: Find the BSON specification and list of implementations here: https://bsonspec.org/