# Migrating indexes with extra keys from Mongo 3.2 to Mongo 3.4

Tags: mongodb

I have the same problem as in this question :

[MongoDB dump from 3.2, restore with 3.4, error index save = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036442/mongodb-dump-from-3-2-restore-with-3-4-error-index-save-null)

In my case, recreating indexes by hand is not an option, I need a script that automates this for migrating my production environment later.

What I have tried so far :

1/ running this in mongo shell on the new database:

```
for (var collection in ["_tempstore", "contracts", "images", "thumbs", "covers", "invoices"]) { 
  db.getCollection("cfs_gridfs." + collection + ".files").createIndex({filename: 1}); 
  db.getCollection("cfs_gridfs." + collection + ".chunks").createIndex({files_id: 1, n: 1}); 
}
```

which fails.

2/ Getting rid of the extraneous `w` key which is the root of the issue in my indexes on my old database by running :

```
db.system.indexes.update({w: {$exists: true}}, {$unset: {w: ""}})
```

which also fails.

What is the correct way to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

I have written a script that i run against my dumped files to sanitize them.

First create those two files :

`sanitize.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DUMP_PATH=$1
for file in $( ls $DUMP_PATH | grep .*\.metadata\.json ); do
  node remove-extraneous-keys-from-indexes.js $DUMP_PATH/$file
done
```

`remove-extraneous-keys-from-indexes.js`

```
const fs = require("fs");
const {promisify} = require("util");

const fileName = process.argv[2];

(async () => {
  const text = await promisify(fs.readFile)(fileName, 'utf8')
  const json = JSON.parse(text)
  json.indexes = json.indexes.map(index => ({
    v: index.v,
    key: index.key,
    name: index.name,
    ns: index.ns
  }))
  await promisify(fs.writeFile)(fileName, JSON.stringify(json))
})()
```

then run

```
$ chmod u+x sanitize.sh
$ ./sanitize.sh path/to/dump/folder
```

Then when I run `mongorestore`, everything is fine.

WARNING : this script assumes you have the latest version of node running. Check this by running `node -v`. It should be `8.6` or more.