# How can I recreate import/export on parse server?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Does anyone know how to recreate import/export from parse.com on parse server?

Or even point me in the right direction to do this?

Comment: https://parse.com/migration

Comment: I do not want to migrate an existing app from parse.com. I want to re create the import/export parse.com functionality in parse server.

Comment: Oh. Yeah, that's too broad for StackOverflow. Maybe put a feature request on Github for Parse Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a third party MongoDB tool for that like [MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/).

Or you can use a Mongo query like mongodump:

```
mongodump -d <database_name> -o <directory_backup>
```

And to "restore/import" that, i used (from directory_backup/dump/):

```
mongorestore -d <database_name> <directory_backup>
```

Check out [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255630/how-to-export-all-collection-in-mongodb) for more one that.

Comment: MongoChef was the solution I eventually found. As far as i'm aware mongo dump cannot import/export specific classes.