# Export Whole Mongodb Database with all collections

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

How can I export my whole database using command?

```
I have tried to export collections from mongoDB compass and it's works.
But I want to export whole DB using command.
```

Comment: mongodump is a good way to take a dump of the entire database. Not sure if MongoDB compass has commandline access. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/

Comment: See here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255630/how-to-export-all-collections-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 10):

**I got an answer. We can do export & import whole mongodb database with command from CMD.**

1.Open CMD run as administrator.

2.Go to your mongo's bin directory. ex.C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin

3.Hit the command for export database.

```
mongodump --archive=DBName.gz --gzip --db DBName
```

4.Hit the command to restore database.

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=DBName.gz --db DBName
```